# How do I add an element to an array-map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

How can I add an element to an array-map in Clojure? I tried using assoc but it doesn't get added? I essentially want to set a default value of 0 for any missing items in the entry array-map.

```
(defn create-entry [doc]
 (let [entry (assoc doc "id" (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID)))]
  (if (empty? (get entry "foo")) (assoc entry "foo" 0))
  (if (empty? (get entry "bar")) (assoc entry "bar" 0))))
```

Update after comments from Carcigenicate:

```
(defn entry [doc]
(as-> (assoc doc "id" (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID))) e
      (if (empty? (get e "foo")) (assoc e "foo" 0) e)
      (if (empty? (get e "bar")) (assoc e "bar" 0) e)))

(defn create-entry [doc]
  (prn (entry doc)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to starting thinking more functional. Note how all the structures you're using are immutable; they themselves can never change. Your second last line makes a copy of `entry`, but you never do anything with it; it's just thrown out. There are a few ways of dealing with situations like this where you need to transform a structure over a couple steps:

- Just use `let`:

  ```
  (let [entry (assoc doc "id" (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID)))
        def-foo (if (empty? (get entry "foo")) (assoc entry "foo" 0) entry)]
    (if (empty? (get def-foo "bar")) (assoc def-foo "bar" 0) def-foo)))
  ```

  Note how the last line uses the `def-foo` copy, instead of the original `entry`.
- Use a threading macro:

  ```
      ; Create a new binding, e, that will hold the result of the previous form
      (as-> (assoc doc "id" (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID))) e
            (if (empty? (get e "foo")) (assoc e "foo" 0) e)
            (if (empty? (get e "bar")) (assoc e "bar" 0) e))
  ```

  `e` is replaced by whatever the previous form evaluated to.

Note though, that if you ever find yourself using `get` and `assoc` on the same object, you might want to consider using `update` instead, which greatly simplifies everything, especially when paired with the `->` threading macro:

```
(-> (assoc doc "id" (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID)))
    (update "foo" #(if (empty? %) 0 %))
    (update "bar" #(if (empty? %) 0 %)))
```

---

I had to make some assumptions about what your intent was, because your code has an error that I didn't notice until after I had already submitted my answer. In your original code, your `if`s don't evaluate to anything when the condition is false. I'm assuming you just don't want to change anything when they're false.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. As you can probably tell i'm very new to Clojure. I have attempted to follow your answer using the threading macro and have updated the post with the code change. However I'm not sure I have interpreted your answer correctly as I am still unable to print a default value for foo or bar.

Comment: @Freid001 You need to call `entry` by wrapping it in parenthesis: `(prn (entry doc))`. Remember, a symbol needs to be the first element in a form to be called. All your code was doing us printing information about the function itself, since you never called it.

Comment: Thanks I can see the default values. I was just using `prn` to log the response to the console.

Comment: As I said before I'm very new to Clojure is there any documentation you could recommend to help me better understand the threading macro concept?

Comment: @Freid001 Np. And the Clojure docs are excellent. If I were you, I'd just start a REPL and mess around with them. Start with `->` though, as it's the simplest. Read over the docs for it, and then play. You'll get it.

Comment: @Freid001 Basically all they do is pass (thread) an argument so you don't have to deal with it. `(-> 1 (* 2) (+ 3))` is exactly the same thing as `(+ (* 1 2) 3)`. The former leads to much nicer code when you start threading through many functions. They basically just help prevent deep nesting. They're a readability helper.

Comment: fwiw `as->` is intended to be used inside an existing threading context, so that it reads like "the thing we've been threading, let's refer to that as `x` for a while". So rather than `(as-> (lots of long stuff here) x (foo))`, it's more readable to see `(-> (lots of long stuff here) (as-> x (foo))`.

Comment: @amalloy I actually didn't know that. Makes sense though given the expression is the first argument. It reads kind of awkward when there's a full expression as the first argument, and the name just kind of floating after it. The arguments being threaded though are in such weird places, without approaching it from an entirely different angle, I wasn't sure how best to write this without just relying on `let`. `as->` semed like the perfect tool here. Is it discouraged from being used outside of other threading macros?

Comment: `as->` is fine. You just introduce a "useless" `->` to reorder the arguments to `as->`.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement Carcigenicate's answer, another suggestion:
I'd use `merge` or `assoc` on a map of defaults:

```
(merge {:default-1 123 :default-2 234} {:default-1 "foo"})
=> {:default-1 "foo", :default-2 234}
```

Note that the order of arguments to `merge` matters i.e. right-most maps take precedence over left-most maps. Your *default* map values will only "survive" if they're not overridden by additional map(s).

```
(def defaults {"foo" 0, "bar" 0})
(defn create-entry [doc]
  (assoc defaults "id" (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID))))
(defn create-entry [doc]
  (merge defaults {"id" (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID))}))
```

Using `assoc` in this example has the same effect, and I'd prefer that version.