# How do I store an array of strings inside defn?

Tags: clojure

I want to store an array of validation errors and then print the errors to the console. How would I best achieve this? I attempted it with the code below however `err` always seems to be set to [].

```
(defn foo-bar [doc]
  (let [err []]
    (if (= (get doc "foo") nil) (conj err "foo is required"))
    (if (= (get doc "bar") nil) (conj err "bar is required"))

    (if (not-empty err) 
      (prn err) 
        ( 
          ;do somthing 
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

As you can probably tell I'm new to Clojure so any help would be gratefully appreciated :)

Comment: `cond->` is good for this kind of "imperative" style in the functional language

Comment: To explain why the code doesn't work -- `(conj err "whatever")` doesn't *change* `err`, it calculates a new value *based on* `err`. If you don't store, return, loop on or rebind that new value, it's simply thrown away.

Comment: A nonidiomatic fix (preserving current logical flow) would be to make it `(let [err (atom [])] ...`, and then `(swap! err conj "foo is required")`, operating on `@err` when you want to retrieve the current value from the atom.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How would I go about rebind the new value?

Comment: Resolved using @leetwinski answer.

Comment: This is very very similar to your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47163312/625403. I'm not closing it as a duplicate, but you should stop and think a bit harder about what immutability means before asking another question just like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as commenters already said, the main problem is you don't change data at all. SInce the data is (generally) immutable, it is idiomatic to pass the result down the processing functions chain. In your case you just discard your updates.

I would go with something like this:

```
(defn validate [data]
  (letfn [(not-nil-v [data field msg errs]
            (if (nil? (data field))
              (conj errs msg)
              errs))]
    (if-let [val-res (seq (->> []
                               (not-nil-v data "foo" "foo is required")
                               (not-nil-v data "bar" "bar is required")))]
      (println val-res)
      (println "everything is ok"))))
#'user/validate

user> (validate {"foo" 1})
(bar is required)
nil

user> (validate {})
(foo is required bar is required)
nil

user> (validate {"foo" 1 "bar" 2})
everything is ok
nil
```